# SQL NOT IN Large Time Response

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, select

I'm facing a problem with a SQL query that returns the values that i want but after a very long time.

what can i change in my code for timing optimization?:

```
select * 
from t1 
where 
(t1.date between '01/01/2016' and '05/01/2016') 
and (t1.section = 'KA') 
and t1.protocol not in (select t2.protocol from t2 where (date between '01/01/2016' and '05/01/2016') and (section = 'KA'))
```

Comment: How many rows are in t1 & t2? What is the structure of t1 & t2?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `not exists`:

```
select t1.* 
from t1 
where t1.date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-05-01' and
      t1.section = 'KA' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.protocol = t1.protocol and
                        t2.date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-05-01' and
                        t2.section = 'KA'
                 );
```

For performance, you want indexes on `t1(section, date, protocol)`. and `t2(protocol, section, date)`.

Comment: Thank you man! that did the trick. why it takes so long with the othr statement? thank you for the support

Comment: @AndreaMorello . . . Different ways of formulating a query can result in different execution plans.  `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` often produces a better execution plan in MySQL than `IN`/`NOT IN`.